# Git push stacks for IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 14.1.4

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Whenever I do git push through VCS/git/push, IDE just stacks at "Pushing...".

Nothing pops up, so was wondering what is causing the problem.

Git push through terminal works fine.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Do _any_ Git operations work from your IntelliJ?

Comment: Not sure. I can't really tell, since it just hangs when I do push,

Comment: Maybe commit works. Only push doesnt work.

Comment: Commit is a local action, while push needs to communicate with the remote repository.  My guess is that there is a configuration problem with the remote.

Comment: Hmmm.... Do you know which conf problem?

Comment: Do you have access to Git from the command line?  What does `git remote show origin` show you?

Comment: :\Development\PokeRPGmain>git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/meme/PokeRPG.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/meme/PokeRPG.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)

Comment: Btw it is fake url...

Comment: Can you push to any other repo on gihub or elsewhere, from IDE or CLI?

Comment: Are you using a SSH key for remote authentication?

Comment: Cannot push at all. I'm using SSH key for remote authentication.

Comment: I can push through terminal, but not through IDE